# Парсинг сложного XML формата <xs:тэг> golang

Tags: xml, golang, xmlparser

Столкнулся с проблемой: почему-то при работе с XML  структурами типа

```
<Тэг1:Тэг2> значение </Тэг1:Тэг2>
```

программа перестает находить данные в XML. Например, если взять файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:data>
  <xs:person id="13">
   <xs:XML_Name></xs:XML_Name>
   <xs:name>
    <xs:first>Abigail</xs:first>
    <xs:last>Kane</xs:last>
   </xs:name>
  </xs:person>
  <xs:person id="14">
   <xs:XML_Name></xs:XML_Name>
   <xs:name>
    <xs:first>James</xs:first>
    <xs:last>Willow</xs:last>
   </xs:name>
  </xs:person>
  <xs:person id="15">
   <xs:XML_Name></xs:XML_Name>
   <xs:name>
    <xs:first>Margareth</xs:first>
    <xs:last>Vera</xs:last>
   </xs:name>
  </xs:person>
  <xs:person id="16">
   <xs:XML_Name></xs:XML_Name>
   <xs:name>
    <xs:first>Lowan</xs:first>
    <xs:last>de Vega</xs:last>
   </xs:name>
  </xs:person>
 </xs:data>
</xs:schema>
```

и попытаться распарсить с помощью структуры:

```
type Data struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"xs:data"`
    PersonList []Person `xml:"xs:person"`
}

type Person struct {
    XML_Name  xml.Name `xml:"xs:person"`
    Id        int      `xml:"xs:id,attr"`
    FirstName string   `xml:"xs:name>xs:first"`
    LastName  string   `xml:"xs:name>xs:last"`
}
```

Все данные полей будут пустыми.

Если же полностью убрать из xml "XS:" - парсинг работает. При построчном чтении файла - такие данные вообще воспринимаются как ссылки на случайное доменное имя.Не могу понять как можно видоизменить структуру для чтения подобных данных?

Объем данных очень большой, поэтому чистить каждое поле в xml-файле от такого сочетания - невозможно

Comment: Вам нужно изучить пространства имен (namespaces) XML и то, как с ними обращаться. Кроме того, образец XML имеет неправильный формат (not well-formed), поскольку префикс пространства имен «xs» не объявлен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас некорретный XML. Префикс `xs` означает пространство имён (namespace). В тег `<xs:data>` необходимо добавить атрибут `xmlns:xs="..."`. Что там внутри кавычек - не принципиально.

После того как вы добавите корректное объявление пространства имён, парсер заработает

```
<xs:data xmlns:xs="http://example/org/xs">
  ...
</xs:data>
```

Пример парсинга: https://go.dev/play/p/Hu_93cJptqK

Если же вам поставщик данных выдаёт документы в таком формате без объявленного пространства имён, то можно сделать трюк - обернуть файл в элемент с объявленным пространством имён.

Полный пример https://go.dev/play/p/PLGJn-aK10I

```
type Wrapper struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"wrapper"`
    Data    Data     `xml:"data"`
}

type Data struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"data"`
    PersonList []Person `xml:"person"`
}

type Person struct {
    XML_Name  xml.Name `xml:"person"`
    Id        int      `xml:"id,attr"`
    FirstName string   `xml:"name>first"`
    LastName  string   `xml:"name>last"`
}

func main() {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.WriteString(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)
    buf.WriteString("\n")
    buf.WriteString(`<xs:wrapper xmlns:xs="http://example.org/xs">`)
    buf.WriteString("\n")
    buf.WriteString(document)
    buf.WriteString("\n")
    buf.WriteString("</xs:wrapper>\n")

    var wrapper Wrapper

    err := xml.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &wrapper)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", wrapper.Data)
}
```

В результате вызовов `WriteString` получится документ такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:wrapper xmlns:xs="http://example.org/xs">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xs:data>
    ...
 </xs:data>
</xs:wrapper>
```

Поле `Data` обёртки `Wrapper` как раз та структура данных, которая соответствует исходному документу.